# QGIS Web Client 2 & QGIS Server features break after adding new project source

Tags: qgis, qgis-server, qgis-web-client

QUESTION:

Ubuntu 18

I have problems with QGIS web client 2 features after install & configure w/ QGIS server.

I must be doing something incorrect with the project html link if I am seeing these issues i detail below, because in the demo all works correctly and the html links do not include wms request.

I see the html links in the demo themesConfig.json are like this:

```
http://qwc2.sourcepole.ch/wms/themes/test
```

So no capabilities request or WMS?

When I leave out the wms request from the html yarn does not want to reload the theme even after symbolic links for project source, wms xml, & mapserv.fcgi

I can only get the map to appear when I do the html link like this:

```
http://qgis.demo/cgi-bin/projects/qgis_mapserv.fcgi?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetCapabilities
```

I assume this is the core of the issues I am seeing. What am I missing?

---

ISSUES:

1: When I use print function, I get 500 internal server error after pressing "print" button.

- test project has a print composer profile setup.
- something in themesConfig.json or Config.json missing or incorrect possibly

2: When I click on the map the pop up window that would show map feature details in the demo quickly disappears and I am sent to a blank white screen and I must refresh browser to get the map back.

- this feature was working with demo project sources & broke when I added my source

3: When I export RASTER & DXF I get "unable to connect localhost:5000"

- same in demo & after I added my project source.
- I see in config.json i need to configure proxy, but details are limited.

4: When I access QWC2 from another system on the network, I am unable to see the test project. The thumbnail and project layers are not showing up.

---

DOCS USED:

- Followed steps here for QGIS server install, sections 12.1 & 12.2: 
  https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/training_manual/qgis_server/index.html
- Followed steps here for QGIS web client 2 after 12.2.6 QGIS-server instructions said to use the older QWC version: 
  https://github.com/qgis/qwc2-demo-app/blob/master/doc/QWC2_Documentation.md

---

RESULTS:

- QGIS install was successful
- can send WMS get capabilities and map requests.

[image]

- QWC2 demo install was successful
- all features working with demo project sources (expect export RASTER & DXF, I get "unable to connect localhost:5000")

[image]

---

- I modified the themesConfig.json & the test project (world.qgs) displays in QWC2 locally on server:

http://qgis.demo/cgi-bin/qgis_mapserv.fcgi?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetCapabilities&map=/home/qgis/projects/world.qgs

or

This (w/ symbolic links):

http://qgis.demo/cgi-bin/projects/qgis_mapserv.fcgi?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetCapabilities

[image]

[image]